# Creating empty array initally as a field in prisma doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, schema, prisma

I am doing project with React Typescript Next and prisma, I am trying to create user with initally empty array as playlists field, I dont get any error but when i refresh my database (mongodb) i cannot see playlists prop on my newly created user. Firstly I thought that if that is empty I just cant see it, but then when i wanted to invoke to it and update this field, I realized that it is not possible.

My schema.prisma file:

```
model User {
  id             String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name           String
  email          String   @unique
  emailVerified  DateTime
  image          String?
  hashedPassword String
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime @updatedAt
  playlists      Playlist[]
  recentSearches Json[]
  liked          Json
}

model Playlist {
  id       String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name     String
  tracks   Json[]
  image    String?
  isPublic Boolean @default(true)
  author   String?
  User     User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId   String  @db.ObjectId
}
```

My register user logic:

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
  try {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await prismadb.user.findUnique({ where: { email } });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res
        .status(422)
        .json({ error: "Email is already taken", cause: "email" });
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
    const user = await prismadb.user.create({
      data: {
        email,
        name,
        hashedPassword,
        image: "",
        emailVerified: new Date(),
        recentSearches: [],
        liked: {},
        playlists: { create: [] },
      },
    });

    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

I tried using create and createMany attribute but nothing worked, I realized that if i use Json[] instead of Playlist[] it works but i want to have Playlists[] as a type.
I expect to create a user with empty array of playlists field in database.

The way i want then update my playlists field

```
const createdPlaylist = await prismadb.playlist.create({
      data: { name: playlistName, tracks: [], userId: user.id },
    });
    
const result = await prismadb.user.update({
    where: { id: user.id },
    data: { playlists: { connect: { id: createdPlaylist.id } } },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, the behaviour for fields that are initially empty or not set explicitly is different from traditional SQL databases. In MongoDB, fields that are not set in a document are not stored in the database. This is different from SQL databases where all columns are present in every row, and empty fields are explicitly represented.

In your Prisma schema, the `playlists` field is defined as an empty array by default:

```
playlists      Playlist[]
```

When you create a new user using Prisma and MongoDB, the `playlists` field will not be stored in the database if it's empty because MongoDB doesn't store fields with empty arrays by default.

If you want to ensure that the `playlists` field is always present in the user document, even if it's initially empty, you can modify your schema to set a default value explicitly for that field:

```
playlists      Playlist[] @default([])
```

After making this change, you may need to regenerate your Prisma client to apply the updated schema:

```
npx prisma generate
```

Comment: When i want to apply @default([]) in prisma file, i got error that it's cannot be done on a relation field so i am affraid it wont work, You said that mongodb doesnt store empty values by default so how can i create this field and then update this?

Comment: Ok nevermind i solved it, everything was working as expected but i just forgot to write `{include: {playlists: true}}`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue, everything was working as expected but I just forgot to write {include: {playlists: true}} on object in find method so I didint see playlists in console.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).